# How to automatically deploy Ec2 instance programmaticaly?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a website, abc.com and our website is like a tournament registration portal and any user landing to our website can make payment and request for a similar portal under the requested site URI, let's say xyz.com.

So once the admin receives the portal request, if he accepts the request, a new EC2 instance would be created for the request site URI, xyz.com. And that site would be a clone of our website with frontend and backend in that instance created.

So I assume automated provisioning is the term for the process, I was told to use ansible but it is not available for a single developer.

So please suggest me the best utility or something within AWS, to accomplish the above-mentioned task.

**Note:** I am using react js as front end and node js as my backend.

Comment: Cloud formation, Terraform, or Ansible are all free, available for use by a single developer and would suffice here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you managed the infrastructure as a Infrastructure as Code based solution (such as [CloudFormation](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/) or [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/)).

For these you would define templates or modules that contain a definition of how the infrastructure would look, then when you need to create a new one you would programmatically create it. For CloudFormation you can use either the CLI or SDK to perform the [create-stack](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cloudformation/create-stack.html) function, passing in the template contents that you would like to create.

Every new site would have its own stack which contains any resources that are required for it to run (servers, security groups, load balancers, databases etc).

If any custom commands need to be run on servers after creation you could have a CloudFormation [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) invoke a [systems manager run command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html) to make these last minute alterations, or instead pass commands in during the EC2 launch within the [user data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html).

Any server would come from a pre build AMI with any configuration and software already prepared (configure the server using [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/), [Chef](https://www.chef.io/) or [Puppet](https://puppet.com/)).

Take a look at these [example application stacks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/sample-templates-appframeworks-us-west-2.html) in CloudFormation that might help to show how it could be used.

Comment: as I mentioned I cannot use ansible, since it is not available for single developerf

Comment: This is a pre step to provision in the configuration of a server image, to ensure that you know the steps to rebuild it. This would not be part of the process you programatically follow :)

Comment: so I can move forward without using ansible? and I can do this process using cloud formation alone? or can I do this with something within AWS? I can see some options from aws like auto calling groups are they useful at a situation like this

Comment: Yes, you would want to create a base image of what the server looks like, after that refer to it in CloudFormation when you create any new AWS resources

Comment: So that means  I need to have a copy of my front end and back end store in S3 bucket and fetch it from there when spinning up a new instance, btw thank you for immediate response and clear solution

Comment: No problem, yes you have the choice of either packaging it with a base AMI that you reference, copying down from S3 as a custom resource or hooking up with a CD solution such as CodeDeploy. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can either use Terraform or cloud formation.Personally , I prefer Terraform.
So as per me, easiest approach would be: You should have pre baked AMI for the EC2 servers hosted for abc.com and you can use the same AMI to build xyz.com also as I assume, both EC2 should have same configuration. The only difference will be dns name which you can customize for new application. That can also be done through terraform.
During deploy, you can customize your new EC2 also ( for example , adding some more software or data) by user data configuration. You can copy resources  from other storage like S3 or you can attach any other storage also. Jenkins is the popular tool to build such pipeline.Initially, effort will be more but once the pipeline will be set, life will be much easier for you.